# Custom function in R outputs null value in global environment, though prints desired output in console

Tags: r, null, outliers

I am an amateur R programmer. I am attempting to write a block of code that cleans data of outliers, outputting the end product as a data.frame. I can view the desired output by including a View() line in the function but I am having trouble creating a data.frame in the global environment. Thus far, the output in the global environment shows up as a null value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(datasets)
View(stackloss)
nums <- unlist(lapply(stackloss, is.numeric)) 
numeric = as.data.frame(stackloss[,nums])

stats = function(x){
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats[5]
}

upper.outlier = as.data.frame(lapply(numeric, stats))
class(upper.outlier)



test = rbind(upper.outlier, numeric)

func = function(x, a) while(x<length(a)){
  x = x+1
  b = a[which(a[x] <= upper.outlier[1,x]),]
  a = b
  if(x == length(a)){View(b)}
}
func(0, test)
```

Comment: It's generally bad-form to reference variables in a function that are not explicitly passed to it or defined internally. There are arguably times when it is very difficult to do otherwise, it often leads to hard-to-find problems when functions are used in difference namespaces. (In this case, `upper.outlier` is used in `func`.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I replaced upper.outlier with y in func. Do you have any ideas about why I'd be able to View(b) without a problem without being able to produce b as a data.frame in the global environment?

Comment: At the end of your function, add `return(b)`, then call with `something <- func(0,test)`. After that, what you view as "b" during the function call will now be available in the calling environment as `something`. Is this what you mean, or have I completely missed the point?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome to "functional programming" :-)